# Problems running Eclipse 64 bit on 64 bit LInux RHEL5

Tags: java, linux, eclipse, jvm

I have a fresh install of the latest Eclipse Helios for Java EE development installed on my computer for 64 bit linux. Usually I can launch Eclipse but after about 5 minutes of use it usually crashes.  Here is an error I get from the command line:

```
#
# A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:
#
#  Internal Error (constantPoolOop.hpp:244), pid=21791, tid=1090197824
#  Error: guarantee(tag_at(which).is_klass(),"Corrupted constant pool")
#
# JRE version: 6.0_18-b07
# Java VM: Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (16.0-b13 mixed mode linux-amd64 )
# An error report file with more information is saved as:
# /home/bob/Desktop/Eclipse 64/eclipse/hs_err_pid21791.log
#
# If you would like to submit a bug report, please visit:
#   http://java.sun.com/webapps/bugreport/crash.jsp
```

**Edit: from hs_err:**

```
#
# A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:
#
#  Internal Error (constantPoolOop.hpp:244), pid=21791, tid=1090197824
#  Error: guarantee(tag_at(which).is_klass(),"Corrupted constant pool")
#
# JRE version: 6.0_18-b07
# Java VM: Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (16.0-b13 mixed mode linux-amd64 )
# If you would like to submit a bug report, please visit:
#   http://java.sun.com/webapps/bugreport/crash.jsp
#

---------------  T H R E A D  ---------------

Current thread (0x000000004fa99800):  JavaThread "main" [_thread_in_vm, id=21792, stack(0x0000000040eb1000,0x0000000040fb2000)]

Stack: [0x0000000040eb1000,0x0000000040fb2000],  sp=0x0000000040faec80,  free space=3f70000000000000018k
Native frames: (J=compiled Java code, j=interpreted, Vv=VM code, C=native code)
V  [libjvm.so+0x70e5f0]
V  [libjvm.so+0x2e3e26]
V  [libjvm.so+0x2de7da]
V  [libjvm.so+0x2dfc8e]
V  [libjvm.so+0x53b41b]
V  [libjvm.so+0x53f29f]
V  [libjvm.so+0x53f4c5]
V  [libjvm.so+0x53f23d]
V  [libjvm.so+0x3ce1e1]
j  java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError.<init>(Ljava/lang/String;)V+2
v  ~StubRoutines::call_stub
V  [libjvm.so+0x3d5e8d]
V  [libjvm.so+0x5d9129]
V  [libjvm.so+0x3d5986]
V  [libjvm.so+0x33257e]
V  [libjvm.so+0x332734]
V  [libjvm.so+0x331e7e]
V  [libjvm.so+0x331fa0]
V  [libjvm.so+0x3a5766]
V  [libjvm.so+0x3a4c9a]
V  [libjvm.so+0x53d422]
V  [libjvm.so+0x53cc27]
V  [libjvm.so+0x3ccef7]
j  org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run([Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/Runnable;)Ljava/lang/Object;+546
v  ~StubRoutines::call_stub
V  [libjvm.so+0x3d5e8d]
V  [libjvm.so+0x5d9129]
V  [libjvm.so+0x3d5cc5]
V  [libjvm.so+0x62ecc1]
V  [libjvm.so+0x632a32]
V  [libjvm.so+0x45fefb]
C  [libjava.so+0x19715]  Java_sun_reflect_NativeMethodAccessorImpl_invoke0+0x15
j  sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Ljava/lang/Object;[Ljava/lang/Object;)Ljava/lang/Object;+87
j  sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Ljava/lang/Object;[Ljava/lang/Object;)Ljava/lang/Object;+6
j  java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Ljava/lang/Object;[Ljava/lang/Object;)Ljava/lang/Object;+161
j  org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework([Ljava/lang/String;[Ljava/net/URL;)V+211
j  org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun([Ljava/lang/String;)V+126
j  org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run([Ljava/lang/String;)I+4
j  org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.main([Ljava/lang/String;)V+10
v  ~StubRoutines::call_stub
V  [libjvm.so+0x3d5e8d]
V  [libjvm.so+0x5d9129]
V  [libjvm.so+0x3d5cc5]
V  [libjvm.so+0x40f0c1]
V  [libjvm.so+0x3fd540]

Java frames: (J=compiled Java code, j=interpreted, Vv=VM code)
j  java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError.<init>(Ljava/lang/String;)V+2
v  ~StubRoutines::call_stub
j  org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run([Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/Runnable;)Ljava/lang/Object;+546
v  ~StubRoutines::call_stub
j  sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Ljava/lang/reflect/Method;Ljava/lang/Object;[Ljava/lang/Object;)Ljava/lang/Object;+0
j  sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Ljava/lang/Object;[Ljava/lang/Object;)Ljava/lang/Object;+87
j  sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Ljava/lang/Object;[Ljava/lang/Object;)Ljava/lang/Object;+6
j  java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Ljava/lang/Object;[Ljava/lang/Object;)Ljava/lang/Object;+161
j  org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework([Ljava/lang/String;[Ljava/net/URL;)V+211
j  org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun([Ljava/lang/String;)V+126
j  org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run([Ljava/lang/String;)I+4
j  org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.main([Ljava/lang/String;)V+10
v  ~StubRoutines::call_stub

---------------  P R O C E S S  ---------------

Java Threads: ( => current thread )
  0x00002aabdc072000 JavaThread "Worker-16" [_thread_blocked, id=23010, stack(0x0000000041771000,0x0000000041872000)]
  0x00002aabdc003800 JavaThread "Worker-15" [_thread_blocked, id=22952, stack(0x00000000418fc000,0x00000000419fd000)]
  0x00002aabd0526800 JavaThread "Worker-11" [_thread_blocked, id=22613, stack(0x0000000042891000,0x0000000042992000)]
  0x000000005126d000 JavaThread "org.eclipse.jdt.internal.ui.text.JavaReconciler" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=21868, stack(0x0000000041d70000,0x0000000041e71000)]


Other Threads:
  0x000000004fb24000 VMThread [stack: 0x0000000040c5a000,0x0000000040d5b000] [id=21801]
  0x00002aabd0009800 WatcherThread [stack: 0x000000004156f000,0x0000000041670000] [id=21808]

VM state:not at safepoint (normal execution)

VM Mutex/Monitor currently owned by a thread: None

Heap
 PSYoungGen      total 1539136K, used 20477K [0x00002aab6f360000, 0x00002aabcd2b0000, 0x00002aabcd2b0000)
  eden space 1538880K, 1% used [0x00002aab6f360000,0x00002aab7075f4f0,0x00002aabcd230000)
  from space 256K, 0% used [0x00002aabcd230000,0x00002aabcd230000,0x00002aabcd270000)
  to   space 256K, 0% used [0x00002aabcd270000,0x00002aabcd270000,0x00002aabcd2b0000)
 PSOldGen        total 3078848K, used 50204K [0x00002aaab34b0000, 0x00002aab6f360000, 0x00002aab6f360000)
  object space 3078848K, 1% used [0x00002aaab34b0000,0x00002aaab65b7238,0x00002aab6f360000)
 PSPermGen       total 86016K, used 86015K [0x00002aaaae0b0000, 0x00002aaab34b0000, 0x00002aaab34b0000)
  object space 86016K, 99% used [0x00002aaaae0b0000,0x00002aaab34aff40,0x00002aaab34b0000)

Dynamic libraries:
40000000-40009000 r-xp 00000000 fd:00 48434050                           /usr/lib/jvm/java-1.6.0-sun-1.6.0.18.x86_64/jre/bin/java
40108000-4010b000 rwxp 00008000 fd:00 48434050                           /usr/lib/jvm/java-1.6.0-sun-1.6.0.18.x86_64/jre/bin/java
4010b000-4010e000 ---p 4010b000 00:00 0 
4010e000-4020c000 rwxp 4010e000 00:00 0 
40243000-40246000 ---p 40243000 00:00 0 
40246000-40344000 rwxp 40246000 00:00 0 
40344000-40347000 ---p 40344000 00:00 0 
40347000-40445000 rwxp 40347000 00:00 0 
40445000-40448000 ---p 40445000 00:00 0 
40448000-40546000 rwxp 40448000 00:00 0 
40764000-40767000 ---p 40764000 00:00 0 
40767000-40865000 rwxp 40767000 00:00 0 
40865000-40868000 ---p 40865000 00:00 0 
40868000-40966000 rwxp 40868000 00:00 0 
40966000-40969000 ---p 40966000 00:00 0 
40969000-40a67000 rwxp 40969000 00:00 0 
40aa1000-40aa4000 ---p 40aa1000 00:00 0 
40aa4000-40ba2000 rwxp 40aa4000 00:00 0 
40c5a000-40c5b000 ---p 40c5a000 00:00 0 
40c5b000-40d5b000 rwxp 40c5b000 00:00 0 
40d5b000-40d5e000 ---p 40d5b000 00:00 0 
40d5e000-40e5c000 rwxp 40d5e000 00:00 0 
40eb1000-40eb4000 ---p 40eb1000 00:00 0 
40eb4000-40fb2000 rwxp 40eb4000 00:00 0 
40fb2000-40fb5000 ---p 40fb2000 00:00 0 
40fb5000-410b3000 rwxp 40fb5000 00:00 0 
4116b000-4116e000 ---p 4116b000 00:00 0 
4116e00
417710
42690000-42790000 rwxp 42690000 00:00 0 
42790                             [heap]
3f2e400000-3f2e41c000 r-xp 00000000 fd:00 32571713                       /lib64/ld-2.5.so
3f2e61b000-3f2e61c000 r-xp 0001b000 fd:00 32571713                       /lib64/ld-2.5.so
3f2e61c000-3f2e61d000 rwxp 0001c000 fd:00 32571713                       /lib64/ld-2.5.so
3f2e800000-3f2e807000 r-xp 00000000 fd:00 48434033                       /usr/lib/jvm/java-1.6.0-sun-1.6.0.18.x86_64/jre/lib/amd64/jli/libjli.so
3f2e807000-3f2e908000 ---p 00007000 fd:00 48434033                       /usr/lib/jvm/java-1.6.0-sun-1.6.0.18.x86_64/jre/lib/amd64/jli/libjli.so
3f2e908000-3f2e90a000 rwxp 00008000 fd:00 48434033                       /usr/lib/jvm/java-1.6.0-sun-1.6.0.18.x86_64/jre/lib/amd64/jli/libjli.so
3f2f400000-3f2f54e000 r-xp 00000000 fd:00 32571714                       /lib64/libc-2.5.so
                   /lib64/libm-2.5.so
3f2fc00000-3f2fc02000 r-xp 00000000 fd:00 32571716                       /lib64/libdl-2.5.so
3f2fc02000-3f2fe02000 ---p 00002000 fd:00 32571716                       /lib64/libdl-2.5.so
3f2fe020                 /usr/lib64/libz.so.1.2.3
3f30800000-3f30802000 r-xp 00000000 fd:00 52658194                       /usr/lib64/libXau.so.6.0.0
3f30802000-3f30a01000 ---p 00002000 fd:00 52658194                       /usr/lib64/libXau.so.6.0.0
3f30a/libX11.so.6.2.0
3f31400000-3f31410000 r-xp 00000000 fd:00 52658198                       /usr/lib64/libXext.so.6.4.0
3f31410000-3f31610000 ---p 00010000 fd:00 52658198                       /usr/lib64/libXext.so.6.4.0
3f31610000-3f31611000 rwxp 00010000 fd:00 52658198                       /usr/lib64/libXext.so.6.4.0
3f31800000-3f3187f000 r-xp 00000000 fd:00 52658203                       /usr/lib64/libfreetype.so.6.3.10
3f3187f000-3f31a7f000 ---p 0007f000 fd:00 52658203                       /usr/lib64/libfreetype.so.6.3.10
3f31a7f000-3f31a84000 rwxp 0007f000 fd:00 52658203                       /usr/lib64/libfreetype.so.6.3.10
3f31c00000-3f31c20000 r-xp 00000000 fd:00 32571717                       /lib64/libexpat.so.0.5.0
3f31c20000-3f31e1f000 ---p 00020000 fd:00 32571717                       /lib64/libexpat.so.0.5.0
3f31e1f000-3f31e22000 rwxp 0001f000 fd:00 32571717                       /lib64/libexpat.so.0.5.0
3f32000000-3f32029000 r-xp 00000000 fd:00 52658204                       /usr/lib64/libfontconfig.so.1.1.0
3f32029000-3f32229000 ---p 00029000 fd:00 52658204                       /usr/lib64/libfontconfig.so.1.1.0
3f322290
3f32809000-3f32a08000 ---p 00009000 fd:00 52658197                       /usr/lib64/libXrender.so.1.3.0
3f32a08000-3f32a09000 rwxp 00008000 fd:00 52658197                       /usr/lib64/libXrender.so.1.3.0
3f32c00000-3f32c02000 r-xp 00000000 fd:00 52658202                       /usr/lib64/libXinerama.so.1.0.0
3f32c02000-3f32e01000 ---p 00002000 fd:00 52658202                       /usr/lib64/libXinerama.so.1.0.0
3f32e01000-3f32e02000 rwxp 00001000 fd:00 52658202                       /usr/lib64/libXinerama.so.1.0.0
3f330
3f33602000-3f33603000 rwxp 00002000 fd:00 52658199                       /usr/lib64/libXrandr.so.2.0.0
3f33800000-3f33805000 r-xp 00000000 fd:00 52658200                       /usr/lib64/libXfixes.so.3.1.0
3f33805000-3f33a04000 ---p 00005000 fd:00 52658200                       /usr/lib64/libXfixes.so.3.1.0
3f33a04000-3f33a05000 rwxp 00004000 fd:00 52658200                       /usr/lib64/libXfixes.so.3.1.0
3f33c00000-3f33c07000 r-xp 00000000 fd:00 32571722                       /lib64/librt-2.5.so
3f33c07000-3f33e07000 ---p 00007000 fd:00 32571722                       /lib64/librt-2.5.so
3f33e07000-3f33e08000 r-xp 00007000 fd:00 32571722                       /lib64/librt-2.5.so
3f33e08000-3f33e09000 rwxp 00008000 fd:00 32571722                       /lib64/librt-2.5.so
3f34c00000-3f34c9d000 r-xp 00000000 fd:00 32571723                       /lib64/libglib-2.0.so.0.1200.3
3f34c9d000-3f34e9c000 ---p 0009d000 fd:00 32571723                       /lib64/libglib-2.0.so.0.1200.3
3f34e9c000-3f34e9e000 rwxp 0009c000 fd:00 32571723                       /lib64/libglib-2.0.so.0.1200.3
3f35400000-3f3543e000 r-xp
3f35c03000-3f35e02000 ---p 00003000 fd:00 32571725                       /lib64/libgmodule-2.0.so.0.1200.3
3f35e02000-3f35e03000 rwxp 00002000 fd:00 32571725                       /lib64/libgmodule-2.0.so.0.1200.3
3f36000000-3f36067000 r-xp 00000000 fd:00 47268159                       /usr/lib64              /usr/lib64/libatk-1.0.so.0.1212.0
3f36800000-3f3682d000 r-xp 00000000 fd:00 47264771                       /usr/lib64/libpangoft2-1.0.so.0.1400.9
3f3682d000-3f36a2d000 ---p 0002d000 fd:00 47264771                       /usr/lib64/libpangoft2-1.0.so.0.1400.9
3f36a2d000-3f36a2e000 rwxp 0002d000 fd:00 47264771                       /usr/lib64/libpangoft2-1.0.so.0.1400.9
3f37017000-3f37216000 ---p 00017000 fd:00 47268909                       /usr/lib64/libgdk_pixbuf-2.0.so.0.1000.4
3f37216000-3f37217000 rwxp 00016000 fd:00 47268909                       /usr/lib64/libgdk_pixbuf-2.0.so.0.1000.4
3f37400000-3f37774000 r-xp 00000000 fd:00 47258024                       /usr/lib64/libgtk-x11-2.0.so.0.1000.4
3f37774000-3f37973000 ---p 00374000 fd:00 47258024                       /usr/lib64/libgtk-x11-2.0.so.0.1000.4
3f37973000-3f3797d000 rwxp 00373000 fd:00 47258024                       /usr/lib64/libgtk-x11-2.0.so.0.1000
3f3808e000-3f38093000 rwxp 0008e000 fd:00 47261608                       /usr/lib64/libgdk-x11-2.0.so.0.1000.4
3f38200000-3f38208000 r-xp 00000000 fd:00 47268161                       /usr/lib64/libXi.so.6.0.0
3f38208000-3f38407000 ---p 00008000 fd:00 47268161                       /usr/lib64/libXi.so.6.0.0
3f38407000-3f38408000 rwxp 00007000 fd:00 47268161                       /usr/lib64/libXi.so.6.0.0
3f38a00000-3f38a15000 r-xp 00000000 fd:00 32571734                       /lib64/libnsl-2.5.so
3f38a15000-3f38c14000 ---p 00015000 fd:00 32571734                       /lib64/libnsl-2.5.so
3f38c14000-3f38c15000 r-xp 00014000 fd:00 32571734                       /lib64/libnsl-2.5.so
3f38c15000-3f38c16000 rwxp 00015000 fd:00 32571734                       /lib64/libnsl-2.5.so
3f38c16000-3f38c18000 rwxp 3f38c16000 00:00 0 
3f3be00000-3f3be04000 r-xp 00000000 fd:00 32571736                       /lib64/libgthrea/libXtst.so.6.1.0
3f41c05000-3f41c06000 rwxp 00005000 fd:00 47266927                       /usr/lib64/libXtst.so.6.1.0
2aaaaaaab000-2aaaaaaac000 r-xs 0000b000 fd:00 33883834                   /home/bob/Desktop/Eclipse 64/eclipse/plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.2.0.v20110502.jar
2
2aaaaaad6000-2aaaaaad8000 r-xs 00
2aaaaabea000-2aaaaac13000 r-xp 00000000 fd:00 48434066                   /usr/lib/jvm/java-1.6.0-sun-1.6.0.18.x86_64/jre/lib/amd64/libjava.so
2aaaaac13000-2aaaaad12000 ---p 00029000 fd:00 48434066                   /usr/lib/jvm/java-1.6.0-sun-1.6.0.18.x86_64/jre/lib/amd64/libjava.so
2aaaaad12000-2aaaaad19000 rwxp 00028000 fd:00 48434066                   /usr/lib/jvm/java-1.6.0-sun-1.6.0.18.x86_64/jre/lib/amd64/libjava.so
2aaaaad19000-2aaaaad1a000 r-xp 2aaaaad19000 00:00 0 
2aaaaad1a000-2aaaaad1b000 rwxp 2aaaaad1a000 00:00 0 
2aaaaad1b000-2aaaaad22000 r-xp 00000000 fd:00 48434091                   /usr/lib/jvm/java-1.6.0-sun-1.6.0.18.x86_64/jre/lib/amd64/native_threads/libhpi.so
2aaaaad22000-2aaaaae23000 ---p 00007000 fd:00 48434091                   /usr/lib/jvm/java-1.6.0-sun-1.6.0.18.x86_64/jre/lib/amd64/native_threads/libhpi.so
2aaaaae23000-2aaaaae25000 rwxp 00008000 fd:00 48434091                   /usr/lib/jvm/java-1.6.0-sun-1.6.0.18.x86_64/jre/lib/amd64/native_threads/libhpi.so
2aaaaae25000-2aaaaae26000 rwxp 2aaaaae25000 00:00 0 
2aaaaae26000-2aaaaaed2000 r-xs 00000
2aabcd8b9000-2aabcdba9000 rwxp 2aabcd8b9000 00:00 0 
2aabcdba9000-2aabce18a000 rwonv/ISO8859-1.so
2aabcefa0000-2aabcefa2000 rwxp 00001000 fd:00 47383053                   /usr/lib64/gconv/ISO8859-1.so
2aabcefa2000-2aabcefb3000 r-xp 00000000 fd:00 48169239                   /usr/lib64/gtk-2.0/2.10.0/engines/libclearlooks.so
2aabcefb3000-2aabcf1b3000 ---p 00011000 fd:00 48169239                   /usr/lib64/gtk-2.0/2.10.0/engines/libclearlooks.so
2aabcf1b3000-2aabcf1b4000 rwxp 00011000 fd:00 48169239                   /usr/lib64/gtk-2.0/2.10.0/engines/libclearlooks.so
2aabcf1b5000-2aabcf1b8000 r-xp 00000000 fd:00 48169144                   /usr/lib64/gtk-2.0/2.10.0/loaders/libpixbufloader-bmp.so
2aabcf1b8000-2aabcf3b7000 ---p 00003000 fd:00 48169144                   /usr/lib64/gtk-2.0/2.10.0/loaders/libpixbufloader-bmp.so
2aabcf3b7000-2aabcf3b8000 rwxp 00002000 fd:00 48169144                   /usr/lib64/gtk-2.0/2.10.0/loaders/libpixbufloader-bmp.so
2aabcf3b8000-2aabcf41b000 rwxp 2aabcf3b8000 00:00 0 
2aabcf41b000-2aa             /usr/lib/jvm/java-1.6.0-sun-1.6.0.18.x86_64/jre/lib/amd64/libnio.so
2aabcf64b000-2aabcf64d000 rwxp 00006000 fd:00 48434079                   /usr/lib/jvm/java-1.6.0-sun-1.6.0.18.x86_64/jre/lib
2aabd33f6000-2aabd4000000 ---p 2aabd33f6000 00:00 0 
2aabd4000000-2aabd75db000 r-xp 00000000 fd:00 47254619                   /usr/lib/locale/locale-archive
2aabd75db000-2aabd75df000 r-xp 00000000 fd:00 48169149                   /usr/lib64/gtk-2.0/2.10.0/loaders/libpixbufloader-png.so
2aabd75df000-2aabd77de000 ---p 00004000 fd:00 48169149                   /usr/lib64/gtk-2.0/2.10.0/loaders/libpixbufloader-png.so
2aabd77de000-2aabd77df000 rwxp 00003000 fd:00 48169149                   /usr/lib64/gtk-2.0/2.10.0/loaders/libpixbufloader-png.so
2aabd77df000-2aabd77e1000 r-xp 00000000 fd:00 48104477                   /usr/lib64/pango/1.5.0/modules/pango-basic-fc.so
2aabd77e1000-2aabd79e1000 ---p 00002000 fd:00 48104477                   /usr/lib64/pango/1.5.0/modules/pango-basic-fc.so
2aabd79e1000-2aabd79e2000 rwxp 00002000 fd:00 48104477                   /usr/lib64/pango/1.5.0/modules/pango-basic-fc.so
2aabd79e2000-2aabd79ed000 r-xp gins/Desktop/Eclipse 6op/Eclipse 64/eclipse/plugins/org.eclipse.wst.jsdt.ui_1.1.101.v201108151912.j
2aabd7fbe000-2aabd8028000 r-xp 00000000 fd:00 48333110                   /usr/share/fonts/dejavu-lgc/DejaVuLGCSans-BoldOblique.ttf
2aabd8028000-2aabd8062000 r-xp 00000000 fd:00 48333121                   /usr/share/fonts/dejavu-lgc/DejaVuLGCSansMono.ttf
2aabd8062000-2aabd809b000 r-xp 00000000 fd:00 48333118                   /usr/share/fonts/dejavu-lgc/DejaVuLGCSansMono-Bold.ttf
2aabd809b000-2aabd80c9000 r-xp 00000000 fd:00 48333120                   /usr/share/fonts/dejavu-lgc/DejaVuLGCSansMono-Oblique.ttf
2aabd80c9000-2aabd80f5000 r-xp 00000000 fd:00 48333119                   /usr/share/fonts/dejavu-lgc/DejaVuLGCSansMono-BoldOblique.ttf
2aabd80f5000-2aabd8116000 r-xs 00175000s/Bluecurve/icon-theme.cache
2aabd8ec8000-2aabd94b9000 r-xp 00000000 fd:00 48373836                   /usr/share/icons/gnome/icon-theme.cache
2aabd94b9000-2aabdaed5000 r-xp 00000000 fd:00 49027191                   /usr/share/icons              /usr/lib/jvm/java-1.6.0-sun-1.6.0.18.x86_64/jre/lib/ext/sunjce_provider.jar
2aabdb589000-2aabdb5d2000 r-xs 003c3000 fd:00 33883908                   /home/bob/Desktop/Eclipse 64/eclipse/plugins/org.eclipse.pde.ui_3.6.100.v20110603.jar
2aabdc000000-2aabdd638000 rwxp 2aabdc000000 00:00 0 
2aabdd638000-2aabe0000000 ---p 2aabdd638000 00:00 0 
2b4e7ca8a000-2b4e7ca8b000 rwxp 2b4e7ca8a000 00:00 0 
2b4e7caba000-2b4e7cabd000 rwxp 2b4e7caba000 00:00 0 
2b4e7cabd000-2b4e7d271000 r-xp 00000000 fd:00 48434095                   /usr/lib/jvm/java-1.6.0-sun-1.6.0.18.x86_64/jre/lib/amd64/server/libjvm.so
2b4e7d271000-2b4e7d371000 ---p 007b4000 fd:00 48434095                   /usr/lib/jvm/java-1.6.0-sun-1.6.0.18.x86_64/jre/lib/amd64/server/libjvm.so
2b4e7d371000-2b4e7d4fb000 rwxp 007b4000 fd:00 48434095                   /usr/lib/jvm/java-1.6.0-sun-1.6.0.18.x86_64/jre/lib/amd64/server/libjvm.so
2b4e7d4fb000-2b4e7d534000 rwxp 2b4e7d4fb000 00:00 0 
7fff17af8000-7fff17b0d000 rwxp 7ffffffea000 00:00 0                      [stack]
ffffffffff600000-ffffffffffe00000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0                  [vdso]

VM Arguments:
java_command: /home/bob/Desktop/Eclipse 64/eclipse/plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.2.0.v20110502.jar -os linux -ws gtk -arch x86_64 -showsplash -launcher /home/bob/Desktop/Eclipse 64/eclipse/eclipse64 -name Eclipse64 --launcher.library /home/bob/Desktop/Eclipse 64/eclipse/plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.gtk.linux.x86_64_1.1.100.v20110505/eclipse_1407.so -startup /home/bob/Desktop/Eclipse 64/eclipse/plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.2.0.v20110502.jar --launcher.overrideVmargs -exitdata e7000c -vm /usr/bin/java -vmargs -jar /home/bob/Desktop/Eclipse 64/eclipse/plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.2.0.v20110502.jar
Launcher Type: SUN_STANDARD

Environment Variables:
PATH=/usr/local/apache-maven/apache-maven-3.0.3/bin:/usr/local/apache-maven/apache-maven-3.0.3/bin:/usr/lib64/qt-3.3/bin:/usr/kerberos/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/games:/home/bob/bin:JAVA_HOME=/usr/java/jdk1.6.0_30/bin:NATIVE_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/lib64/:
LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.6.0-sun-1.6.0.18.x86_64/jre/lib/amd64/server:/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.6.0-sun-1.6.0.18.x86_64/jre/lib/amd64:/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.6.0-sun-1.6.0.18.x86_64/jre/../lib/amd64
SHELL=/bin/bash
DISPLAY=:0.0

Signal Handlers:
SIGSEGV: [libjvm.so+0x70f1a0], sa_mask[0]=0x7ffbfeff, sa_flags=0x10000004
SIGBUS: [libjvm.so+0x70f1a0], sa_mask[0]=0x7ffbfeff, sa_flags=0x10000004
SIGFPE: [libjvm.so+0x5d7f70], sa_mask[0]=0x7ffbfeff, sa_flags=0x10000004
SIGPIPE: [libjvm.so+0x5d7f70], sa_mask[0]=0x7ffbfeff, sa_flags=0x10000004
SIGXFSZ: [libjvm.so+0x5d7f70], sa_mask[0]=0x7ffbfeff, sa_flags=0x10000004
SIGILL: [libjvm.so+0x5d7f70], sa_mask[0]=0x7ffbfeff, sa_flags=0x10000004
SIGUSR1: SIG_DFL, sa_mask[0]=0x00000000, sa_flags=0x00000000
SIGUSR2: [libjvm.so+0x5da790], sa_mask[0]=0x00000000, sa_flags=0x10000004
SIGHUP: [libjvm.so+0x5da4e0], sa_mask[0]=0x7ffbfeff, sa_flags=0x10000004
SIGINT: [libjvm.so+0x5da4e0], sa_mask[0]=0x7ffbfeff, sa_flags=0x10000004
SIGTERM: [libjvm.so+0x5da4e0], sa_mask[0]=0x7ffbfeff, sa_flags=0x10000004
SIGQUIT: [libjvm.so+0x5da4e0], sa_mask[0]=0x7ffbfeff, sa_flags=0x10000004


---------------  S Y S T E M  ---------------

OS:Red Hat Enterprise Linux Client release 5.5 (Tikanga)

uname:Linux 2.6.18-194.el5 #1 SMP Tue Mar 16 21:52:39 EDT 2010 x86_64
libc:glibc 2.5 NPTL 2.5 
rlimit: STACK 10240k, CORE 0k, NPROC 155648, NOFILE 1024, AS infinity
load average:1.00 1.01 0.94

CPU:total 8 (8 cores per cpu, 2 threads per core) family 6 model 26 stepping 5, cmov, cx8, fxsr, mmx, sse, sse2, sse3, ssse3, sse4.1, sse4.2, popcnt, ht

Memory: 4k page, physical 18471776k(13695872k free), swap 2097144k(2097144k free)

vm_info: Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (16.0-b13) for linux-amd64 JRE (1.6.0_18-b07), built on Dec 17 2009 13:42:22 by "java_re" with gcc 3.2.2 (SuSE Linux)

time: Thu Jan 26 13:50:25 2012
elapsed time: 3266 seconds
```

Comment: What does hs_err_pid21791.log file contain? Share it as it has the error trace

Comment: Alfabravo updated with hs_err_pid21791.log.  @Jivings What distribution? Linux? it's RHEL 5. Eclipse jee indigo SR1 linux gtk-x86_64

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your JVM has crashed.  There are a few reasons why it might have done so, but the end result is most likely going to be resolved by installing a newer (or sometimes older) JVM.  If problems persist with a number of different JVMs, then start looking for yet-to-be-resolved bugs (rare, but it happens) or library incompatibilities / missing prerequisites (much more common).

You might want to try the "client" version of the JVM too, especially for running something like eclipse, which typically won't benefit from the "run for a very long time before shutting down" optimizations that the "server" JVM offering does.

In the past, one would submit the log file you are displaying to SUN and they would work it into the software maintenance / bug fixing queue.  I'm sure that someone at Oracle accepts them now, but I haven't submitted one since the corporate switchover.

Comment: I have submitted this as a bug and I received a response from oracle.

Comment: I also have the latest JDK and set JAVA_HOME to point to the new JDK. There were applications that required a 64 bit JVM especially for precompiled native files that can only run in 64 bit environments there were problems with word lengths whene clipse woudln't select the right 64 bit runtime to use. So I uninstalled everything and reinstalled this 64 bit eclipse. Now my probablem possibly is getting it to use the correct 64 bit JVM. I've also heard people say that increasing the memory allocated can fix these types of problems but so far that hasn't worked for me.

Comment: A while back, I had to pick a specific JVM from many installed for my Eclipse setup.  While it should work after uninstalling the "other" jvms (barring the bug in the JVM), you might also want to edit the `eclipse.ini` file as specified here 'http://wiki.eclipse.org/Eclipse.ini' to get better control over which JVM eclipse opts to use.  I'd try rolling back a JVM release or two.  Sometimes bug fixe releases can introduce new issues in scenarios that were unexpected.

Comment: is setting the JDK the same as setting the JVM? I don't think I actually see or use teh word "JVM" in my configuration of eclipse I either see JDK or JRE.

Comment: The JDK has an embedded JRE and a lot of development tools.  The JRE consists of a JVM and just the runtime tools.  Hope this helps.  In either case, you probably want something with a different build number (check the archives since you're on latest), either one should provide you with a JVM.